# React TypeScript: useRef to Link

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to use useRef with Link

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const myLink = useRef<Link>(null);
...
myLink.current.click()
...

<Link to={{pathname: '/terms'}} id='myLink' ref={myLink} />
```

the error I get is `Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Link<any>'.ts(2339)`

I'm currently using the below but i want to move to useRef

```
    const myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');
    if (myLink) myLink.click();
```

Answer (score 4):

As the typescript error says, `Link` component cannot be clicked as simply as anchor. There are two proposed solutions to this.

1. Change Link to `<a href="...">` and use `HTMLAnchorElement` type in the `useRef`.
2. Or if you want to stay using `Link` component from `react-router-dom`, you can access the `props` of the link component.

```
if (myLink.current) {
    window.location.assign(myLink.current.props.to.toString()); // redirect to the to prop on Link component
}
```

Comment: I tried option 2 and I get a compile error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions` from  `if (myLink.current) myLink.current.props.to;`

Comment: Sure you did. `to` is only assigned a value to be redirected to. I will edit the answer for completeness.

Comment: the page completely refreshes now and redirects to `http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]` when using the .click() above the page doesn't completely refresh giving that flash of un styled content but does load the correct page

Comment: You should pass only string to the `to` prop in link, instead of `to={{ pathname: '/terms' }}` only `to="/terms"`

Answer (score 0):

I went with Kryštof Řeháček #1 solution. Here's the code

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const linkRef = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (linkRef.current) linkRef.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <a ref={linkRef} href={'/some-url'} style={{ display: 'none' }}></a>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to some url</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```